# Identifying differing usernames in two data sets

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

Say I have two sets of data in csvs, one smaller containing usernames, first names and last names, one larger with similar data and my objective is to identify rows with the same first and last name, but different usernames and output the two usernames along with the first name and last to another csv with columns like fname, lname, uname_dataset1, uname_dataset2

What would be the best way to go about this using Python?

Sample data set 1:

```
"u_last_name","u_first_name","u_middle_name","u_dept","u_title","u_emp_id","u_ad_account","u_ad_email"
"Smith","John","N/A"," TEST DEPARTMENT5","TestJobTitle",,"TestADUName3","testemail5@domain.mail""
"Doe","Jane","N/A","000350 - TEST DEPARTMENT4","TestJobTitle2",,"TestADUName3","testemail4@domain.mail""
"Rogers","Bob",,"003107 - TEST DEPARTMENT2","TestJobTitle3",,"TestUName2","testemail2@domain.mail"
"Adams","Mike",,"003107 - TEST DEPARTMENT","TestJobTitle4",,"j3fox","testemail@domain.mail"
```

Sample data set 2:

```
Employee ID,Employee Name Current,Identity Active Directory ID Current,Employee Work Email Address Current,Position Number,Employee Record,Department Code,Department,
10493692,"Potential Last Name Middle Name, First Name",TestADUname,,40812966,0,000303,000303 - TESTDEPARTMENT,
10432545,"LastName2, FName2",TestADUName2,testemail2@mail.test,40837987,1,000314,000314 - TESTDEPARTMENT2,
10470189,"LastName3, PotentialMName FirstName",TestADUname3,testemail2@mail.test,40777394,0,000383,000383 - TESTDEPARTMENT3,
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data or the two files?

Comment: Actually looking at the second data set... what I initially proposed may not be ideal and there are *gasp* employee IDs which will be invaluable in this endeavor. Sample data added!

Comment: Can you show what your expected output would be for that sample data?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a dictionary then iterate through the smaller file storing the data into the dictionary using the first and last name as the dictionary key.  Then iterate the second csv checking at each line if the first and last combo exists in the dictionary and update it with new information if so.

Rough example...

```
data = {}
with open("file1.csv") as csv1:
    for line in csv1.read().split("\n"):
        items = line.split(",")
        first = items[0]
        last = items[1]
        data[(first,last)] = items[2:]
with open("file2.csv") as csv2:
    for line in csv2.read().split("\n"):
        items = line.split(",")
        key = (items[0],items[1])
        if key in data:
            data[key].append(items[2:])
```

then you can write the data to another file like any other.

```
with open("newfile.csv", "wt") as newfile:
    for key, value in data.items():
        line = ",".join([*key] + value) + "\n"
        newfile.write(line)
```